# Calculate cache miss manually [ Exercice ]

Tags: caching, memory, memory-address

While revising for exeams, i struggled with a pretty basic problem, but i don't seem to get an answer...

So,in the exercice we have 16 bit memory address, a cache with 256 lines, and 16 byte line ( 4 words of 32 bits).

Suppose a program that executes these instructions :

```
Int A[512], i;
for (i = O; i < 256; i++) {
  A [i+256] A [i] + i ;
}
```

The array A is stored at the address x0000, and i is stored in a register.
They ask how many cache miss, this program will generate ?

My answer is : 64 misses. Since, we work with a 4 words bloc, at each miss we will get a bloc of 4 words, and we loop for 256, so 256/4.

Is that correct ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: whats the size of int ?

Comment: Int is just the type of the array.